# Search direction, select polygons and show kml info Google Maps in php

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I have a map what parse an kml and draws all polygons and show data in infowindow. I can select distintcs polygons and see the info. I don´t know how complete and implement next:

- Before load de kml polygons, i would can enter a direction. When the marker gets this direction, show the kml polygons in a radius of "x" meters. Example: 1.000 meters.
- When kml layer appears and select some polygons, send a query with one field of polygon data to an mysql database, to search this data in one table.
- I need instead select polygons by clicking on them, draw a polygon or a circle and see the data of selected polygons in a table below map.
- Hide default places Google maps shows
- If i select a direction from other town, must show the kml of this town. I have one kml per town

I'm starting to work with maps looking at an example and I'm lost. I see the documentation but I don't understand how to associate everything I need. I appreciate any help.

At this moment, i have only this:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Secc</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Poligono desde repositorio local com google maps">
    
 
<style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
    </style>
 
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAgMc7HbC5-xPkWbFR74sXzzE9nexkAc1A&signed_in=true&sensor=false&v=3.exp"></script>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ProjectedOverlay.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var mapa;
    function iniciar(){
        var mapaoption = {
            zoom: 8,
 
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
 
        mapa = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapaoption);
 
        var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({map: mapa});
 
        geoXml.parse('kml/6.kml');
        google.maps.event.addListener(mapa,'click',function(event){
            kasihtanda(event.latLng);
            
            
        });
    }
    
</script>
</head>
<body onload="iniciar()">
 
<h2>Secc</h2>
 <div id="map" style="height:500px"></div>
 
</body>
```

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Lamento comentarte que no damos sugerencias sobre uso, implementacion de librerias, si se te dificulta la lectura de la documentacion, deberias solicitar ayuda a los creadores de dicha documentacion, si hay algun error especifico, entonces solicita ayuda y documenta el error para poder ayudarte, recueda siempre dejar un [mre]